# Apple Developer Program Renewal - Impact on Apps on the Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I've seen similar question but didn't find one that answered fully my questions. Here it is:

My developer program expires in August 2012. I have apps on the App store that have a distribution provisioning profile created with a certificate that expires in December 2012.

1. When I renew my developer program in August, will my apps continue to work without me having to take any actions on existing device and also be available on the app store?
2. When my certificate expires in December 2012, do I need to recreate a new certificate, then a new distribution provisioning profile and then re-submit the exact same code to Apple to keep the apps installed working and also so that they are available on the Apple store?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's app store policies, not programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your apps will continue to work and be available in the App Store if you renew your developer program membership.  If you do not renew it, your apps will no longer be available in the App Store, although people who have currently installed versions will still be able to use them.
2. When your certificate expires, there should be an option to renew it on the provisioning portal.  You do not need to resubmit the app again as the one that is already in the App Store is still valid.  However, the valid certificate is needed if you ever want to submit an update to the app or submit any new apps.